# Building protobuf 3.9.4 on windows with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build protobuf 3.9.4 on windows with cmake, but when i click 'configure', I get a message saying 'LINK : fatal error LNK1101: incorrect MSPDB140.DLL version; recheck installation of this product'.

Does anybody have any clue what's going on here?

Something's wrong with Visual Studio, most likely, but I'm not sure what.

I tried googling for solutions, but none of them relate to my problem.

P.S.
I'm using the gui version of cmake.

Comment: `Something's wrong with Visual Studio, most likely` - Yes. And most likely this is **unrelated** both to CMake and protobuf.

Answer (score 2):

There is an useful example of CMake scripts patching needed to build protobuf 3.4.1 with Visual Studio 2017 using vcpkg.

```
#region PDFsharp - A .NET library for processing PDF
//
// Authors:
//   Stefan Lange
diff --git a/cmake/CMakeLists.txt b/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
index 7618ba2..d282a60 100644
--- a/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/cmake/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -165,8 +165,10 @@ endif (protobuf_UNICODE)

 include(libprotobuf-lite.cmake)
 include(libprotobuf.cmake)
-include(libprotoc.cmake)
-include(protoc.cmake)
+if(protobuf_BUILD_COMPILER)
+  include(libprotoc.cmake)
+  include(protoc.cmake)
+endif()

 if (protobuf_BUILD_TESTS)
   include(tests.cmake)

diff --git a/cmake/install.cmake b/cmake/install.cmake
index 441bf55..20b3aa0 100644
--- a/cmake/install.cmake
+++ b/cmake/install.cmake
@@ -1,14 +1,17 @@
 include(GNUInstallDirs)

+set(LIBRARIES_TO_SET_DEST libprotobuf-lite libprotobuf)
+if(protobuf_BUILD_COMPILER)
+  list(APPEND LIBRARIES_TO_SET_DEST libprotoc)
+endif()
+
 configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf.pc.cmake
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf.pc @ONLY)
 configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf-lite.pc.cmake
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf-lite.pc @ONLY)

 foreach(_library
-  libprotobuf-lite
-  libprotobuf
-  libprotoc)
+  ${LIBRARIES_TO_SET_DEST})
   set_property(TARGET ${_library}
     PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
     $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${protobuf_source_dir}/src>
@@ -19,8 +22,10 @@ foreach(_library
     ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} COMPONENT ${_library})
 endforeach()

-install(TARGETS protoc EXPORT protobuf-targets
-  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} COMPONENT protoc)
+if(protobuf_BUILD_COMPILER)
+  install(TARGETS protoc EXPORT protobuf-targets
+    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} COMPONENT protoc)
+endif()

 install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf.pc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/protobuf-lite.pc DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig")

@@ -101,7 +106,12 @@ configure_file(protobuf-options.cmake
   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/protobuf-options.cmake @ONLY)

 # Allows the build directory to be used as a find directory.
-export(TARGETS libprotobuf-lite libprotobuf libprotoc protoc
+set(FIND_DIRS libprotobuf-lite libprotobuf)
+if(protobuf_BUILD_COMPILER)
+  list(APPEND FIND_DIRS libprotoc protoc)
+endif()
+
+export(TARGETS ${FIND_DIRS}
   NAMESPACE protobuf::
   FILE ${CMAKE_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}/protobuf-targets.cmake
 )
```

Most probably easiest way to get 3.9.4 building is to upgrade original [protobuf 3.4.1 vcpkg port](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/protobuf). My experience with building C/C++ ports using vcpkg is a positive one so far.